# События Event в WinApi

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот на MSDN есть пример вызова GetAddrInfoExW, приведу только небольшую часть:

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfoexw

Там есть пример вызова функции CreateEvent:

```
QueryContext.CompleteEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
```

Но, в описании функции CreateEvent на том же MSDN`е нет ни какого QueryContext.CompleteEvent, CreateEvent возвращает обычный HANDLE:

```
HANDLE CreateEventA(
  LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpEventAttributes,
  BOOL                  bManualReset,
  BOOL                  bInitialState,
  LPCSTR                lpName
);
```

Я что то не пойму что такое  QueryContext.CompleteEvent и откуда он вообще взялся ?

Comment: Это просто дополнительный тип и переменная из примера.

Comment: `QueryContext.CompleteEvent` же объявлено там прямо в примере как `HANDLE`.

Comment: user7860670, вроде бы не объявлена, как HANDLE. Ну или скорее всего я что то не допонимаю.

Comment: Здесь или тот же или очень похожий пример https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/DNSAsyncNetworkNameResolution/cpp/ResolveName.cpp

Comment: Alex R., ага, почти такой же. И там точно такая же строка:  QueryContext.CompleteEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);  И я не могу понять QueryContext.CompleteEvent == HANDLE ? Как это ?

Comment: Что-то у вас затруднения на ровном месте. Найдите в коде объявление `QueryContext`, посмотрите, какой тип у этой переменной, найдите объявление этого типа, найдите объявление поля `CompleteEvent`, посмотрите, какой тип у этого поля. А чтобы привлечь внимание других пользователей перед их именем надо ставить @.

Answer (score 4):

Прокоментирую для вас [код](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfoexw)

```
int __cdecl wmain( _In_ int Argc, PWCHAR Argv[]) {
INT                 Error = ERROR_SUCCESS;
WSADATA             wsaData;
BOOL                IsWSAStartupCalled = FALSE;
ADDRINFOEX          Hints;
QUERY_CONTEXT       QueryContext; // Вот отсюда он взялся

// .. пропускаю кусок

QueryContext.CompleteEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
// Создали Event событие
if (QueryContext.CompleteEvent == NULL)
{
  // ...  Если не создалось - ошибка
}
// Делаем вызов
Error = GetAddrInfoExW(Argv[1], NULL, NS_DNS, NULL, &Hints,
                       &QueryContext.QueryResults, NULL,
                       &QueryContext.QueryOverlapped,
                       QueryCompleteCallback,
                       &CancelHandle);
// Так как мы передали Event - ответ должен быть PENDING    
if (Error != WSA_IO_PENDING)
{  // Если ответ не PENDING, ответ 0 не будет, а  ошибку обработает код ниже, который в QueryCompleteCallback
    QueryCompleteCallback(Error, 0, &QueryContext.QueryOverlapped); 
    goto exit; // и на выход
}
//  Ждем время  QueryTimeout = 5 секунд пока не произойдёт событие
if (WaitForSingleObject(QueryContext.CompleteEvent,
                        QueryTimeout)  == WAIT_TIMEOUT )
{

    wprintf(L"Пишем что недождались ");

    GetAddrInfoExCancel(&CancelHandle); // Отмена вызова

    WaitForSingleObject(QueryContext.CompleteEvent, INFINITE);// Ждём отмену до бесконечности
}
```

А тут ещё хитрость, они передали каллбек, `QueryCompleteCallback` (ниже по коду) будет вызвано в то время, пока будет идти первый WaitForSingleObject.

Это обычный механизм обращения с Overlapped-event. Похожее можно делать и с чтением файла и с другими операциями, которые могут растянуться во времени.

`HANDLE` позволяет хранить в себе какие угодно kernel обьекты. Файлы, pipe-ы, Thread, их список [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/handle-inheritance) а функции собраны [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/kernel-objects) (msdn) в функциях есть "лишнии" обьекты которые не имеют хандлов.

Есть специальные функции `NtQueryObject` и подобных - которые могут узнать тип хандла. Особенность хандла в том, что для любого хандла можно делать `CloseHandle`,  будь то файл, Event, Thread, Process и так далее. Да, в самом низу примера от микрософт - они закрывают хандл. Наверно это для удобства сделано. Так уже сложилось начиная ещё с первых (или вторых) версий винды так принято с хандлами делать.